# Installing python package fails with Package 'example' requires a different Python: 2.7.12 not in '>=2.5, >=3.0' , although version should fit

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I'm trying to install a python package, but it fails with :

```
pip2 install ./example-0.1.0-py2-none-any.whl
```

> ERROR: Package 'example' requires a different Python: 2.7.12 not in '>=2.5, >=3.0'

So this error message is wrong imo , 2.7.12 is obviously >=2.5 .

This seems to only fail with new pip versions and python2.
All other combinations of python/pip/setuptools seem to work, see the table below for more details.

[image: Testing results]

Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The metadata field [`Requires-Python`](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata/#requires-python) uses the version specifiers syntax which is documented in [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-specifiers):

> The comma (",") is equivalent to a logical **and** operator

2.7.12 is not greater than *both* >=2.5 and >=3.0, therefore the installation should be refused.

The package metadata is likely incorrect.  They could have just used >=2.5, since that already includes anything >=3.0.

Older versions of `pip` don't parse the `Requires-Python` field. The checks on this metadata only work with `pip>=9.0.0`.